# Is there a malformation in my GeoJSON or a bug in my D3 code?

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I am new to d3 and GeoJson. I have [this](https://gist.github.com/AbeHandler/056f489eaa05020d3078) GeoJSON which displays on [geojson lint](http://geojsonlint.com/). I am trying to display the GeoJSON as a map with the following code:

```
var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var projection = d3.geo.transverseMercator().translate([width / 2, height / 2]).scale(150).center(-90.088, 29.957);

var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

d3.json("orleans.json", function(json) {
    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path);
});
```

The second to last line .attr("d", path) is throwing the following error deep in the d3 stack trace:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL8.76110196153104,1051.238898038469L8.76110196153104,108.76110196153104L951.238898038469,108.76110196153104L951.238898038469,1051.238898038469LNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNZMNaN
```

Is there a problem with my GeoJSON? Or a problem with how I am using the GeoJSON with D3? It seems like this error comes from malformed input to D3 -- but my GeoJSON lints. So maybe this is a problem with my D3 syntax and not my GeoJSON?

The GeoJSON does seem like it is getting loaded properly. When I console.log(json) right after the call 
to `d3.json("orleans.json", function(json)` it shows the following:

[image]

Comment: Did you verify that the JSON is loaded correctly?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I don't know how to do that. Can you explain how?

Comment: E.g. `console.log(json)`.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks. Do I put that in the call back after the part that says "function(json) {" ?

Comment: Yes, and then check the debug console of your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

- The `.center()` function takes a single array argument and not two.
- The transverse mercator projection doesn't support antimeridian cutting.

To fix, pass an array instead of two numbers and restrict the center to -90 degrees or less. Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cpfnJAOIPbuViPnORg1w?p=preview).